# Normalizing the table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I have a table whose structure is given in the figure below:

[image]

My need is to write query such that, there is only n rows, where n is the total number of distinct names in the above table. And, all the entries in various columns for each names should be included in that row itself. The final output should look like this :

[image]

I first considered using the UNION operator, but, could not use it, because, I am not sure about the various columns that are present in the table. That is , I don't know the columns in the table, because, new columns may be inserted at run time. But, I have an added advantage that, number of columns will be 7, which will be same all the time. The only thing I don't know is their names.

And, when printing this table into paper, how is it possible to remove all the "NULL" and replace it with blanks...?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `UNION`, you need `GROUP BY`.

It looks like you assume that no student could have several non-NULL values for some mark.

It is bad idea to change table structure on the fly. Better store marks' names in additional table. This way your query would look as follows:

```
SELECT name
  , IF(MAX(mark1) IS NOT NULL, MAX(mark1), '') AS mark1
  , IF(MAX(mark2) IS NOT NULL, MAX(mark2), '') AS mark2
  , IF(MAX(mark3) IS NOT NULL, MAX(mark3), '') AS mark3
  , IF(MAX(mark4) IS NOT NULL, MAX(mark4), '') AS mark4
  , IF(MAX(mark5) IS NOT NULL, MAX(mark5), '') AS mark5
  , IF(MAX(mark6) IS NOT NULL, MAX(mark6), '') AS mark6
  FROM name_marks
  GROUP BY name
;
```

[See it on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfe8e/5)

But, again, saving names as many times as many marks a student has, is also a bad idea. It is better to create a table `students` with `id` and `name` columns, and reference it by `id`. And saving a record with columns for all possible marks is also a bad idea. It is better to create a `courses` table with `id` and `course` columns, and a table `marks` with `student_id`, `course_id` and `mark` columns. This would be optimal in means of data size, and flexibility (you a free to define as many courses as you want).

Comment: This is actually what I wanted, but, in my case this won't work out, as I am unsure of the column names in the table. I am iworking with a java program. So, I need to store the new table from within the Java program.

Comment: You could try to get actual column names from information_schema table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/columns-table.html. Also, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111980/mysql-referring-to-columns-by-numbers.