# Updating a column by referring to it with its number

Tags: php, mysql

Good evening ..
I am posting a form with values that include the number of the column in the data base (and not it's name) , so i want to update the field that the column name refers to,
here is my code :

```
$hours=$_POST['hour'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$s=$_POST['subject'];
$res=mysql_query("UPDATE study SET [$s] ='$hours' WHERE day='$date' ");
```

Where $s is an integer that equals the number of the wanted column. But it doesnt work . so is there a way to refer to a column by it's number rather than it's name ?

Comment: Please show what `SHOW CRATE TABLE study` returns.

Comment: All SQL commands require column names, not numbers.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183465/is-it-possible-to-sql-update-using-row-and-column-numbers

Comment: ok .. i guess i would have to run a query first to get column name depending on its number .. would that be mysql_field_name ?

Comment: Why do you need to refer to columns by number. This sounds like poor design - and a potential security vulnerability.

Comment: The reason is .. i want the user to be able to input something into any of the columns , then retrieve that data in the target page through a loop. so i wont have to repeat the code for each and every column . anyway i solved it through mysql_field_name ...

Answer (score 0):

According to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111980/mysql-referring-to-columns-by-numbers), it seems you can only do that by using the `information_schema` table.

Answer (score 0):

Add an *autoincrement* column that carries the unique number of the row to an existing table

```
 ALTER TABLE mytable ADD idnum INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

(or add the field in a new table

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  idnum INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 ... )
```

And set *idnum* as `PRIMARY KEY`.

So that all rows have a unique number created by MySQL automatically. To insert a row, set the field to *null* and MySQL sets the number automatically

```
INSERT INTO mytable (idnum, ...) VALUES (null, ...);
```

Note that you can retrieve the *idnum* that MySQL set automatically thanks to PHP APIs, eg for *mysqli* ([see this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)),

```
$lastid = $mysqli->insert_id(); // $mysqli being the mysqli object
```

Then to update a value, you have to store somewhere (preferably in the *session* rather than on the page [since the user can modify it in this case - unless it doesn't matter])

```
// Modify field form
...SELECT idnum,nhours FROM mytable WHERE thedate = ...
$_SESSION['idnum'] = $row['idnum'];
...
// Display form ...

// Form processing
// Check first if SESSION has an idnum (an other parameters) in case the user hacked the page and submit a "special" form ...
/// Then
$res=mysql_query("UPDATE study SET nhours='$hours' WHERE idnum=" . $_SESSION['idnum']);
```